# How to limit returns on an edition search using isbnlib library in Python?

Tags: python, isbn, isbnlib

Right now I have:

```
editions = isbnlib.editions(isbn)
print(editions)
```

This returns about 100 similar isbns to the one entered within the parentheses. The problem is, this really slows down my program unnecessarily, as I only want 4 or 5 results. Is there a way I can fix this?

Here you can find an example project using .editions() from their docs: https://github.com/xlcnd/isbnlib/blob/master/isbnlib/test/test_editions.py

And a link to the Python library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbnlib/3.7.2

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at their code, it doesn't look like the API was written to support this. If you are familiar with python code you could always take a peak and see if you could rewrite what they are doing as more of a generator, etc.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show a _**real**_ ISBN you are using. Use either `editions(isbn, service= ‘openl’)` or `editions(isbn, service=‘thingl’)` to restrict the query to only one Library.

Answer (score 1):

Install `isbnlib-3.8.3+` and use `editions(isbn, service= ‘any’)` to *minimize* the numbers of entries and *maximize* the probabilities of getting a non-empty answer.